# Unexpected Output while appending lists to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a very stripped out version of the code of the problem I am trying to solve.

I tried to debug the code using print(x). But I can't understand why in the world is [6,1] repeatedly appending to coordinatesofattack. Any help will be appreciated for its weight in gold.

```py
obstaclecoordinates=[]
coordinatesofattack=[]
n=5
x=[1,1]
while x not in obstaclecoordinates:
    coordinatesofattack.append(x)
    x[0]+=1
    print(x)
    if x[0]>n:
        break
    else:
        continue
print(coordinatesofattack)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT: [[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1]]

REAL OUTPUT:   [[6,1], [6,1], [6,1], [6,1], [6,1]]

Comment: You keep modifying the list that you append. Try: `coordinatesofattack.append(x[:])` to append a *copy* of the list.

Comment: Why is that a problem? And what does x[:] do? Appreciate that!

Comment: `x[:]` is a *copy* of the list `x`. A shallow copy.

Comment: Got it!!! Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you keep modifying the list that you append. You need to create a copy inside the while loop.

```
obstaclecoordinates=[]
coordinatesofattack=[]
n=5
x=[1,1]
while x not in obstaclecoordinates:
    coordinatesofattack.append(x[:])
    x[0]+=1
    print(x)
    if x[0]>n:
        break
    else:
        continue
print(coordinatesofattack)
```

Comment: Yeah! Actually for some stupid reason I can't accept before 6 minutes and it was way past my bedtime here at India! Cheers!